# Spannable и Html не работают совместно

Tags: java, android, html, textview, spannable

Использую `spannable` для реализации сносок в приложении:

```
 private SpannableStringBuilder addClickablePart(String str) {
    SpannableStringBuilder ssb = new SpannableStringBuilder(str);

    int idx1 = str.indexOf("[");
    int idx2 = 0;

    while (idx1 != -1) {
        idx2 = str.indexOf("]", idx1) + 1;

        String clickString = str.substring(idx1, idx2);

        ssb.setSpan(new ClickableSpan() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View widget) {

            }
        }, idx1, idx2, 0);
        idx1 = str.indexOf("[", idx2);
    }
    return ssb;
}

pageContent.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
pageContent.setText(addClickablePart(pageContentStr), TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
```

Если в метод `setText` я добавлю `Html.fromHtml()`, то `spannable` перестает работать, есть ли какие-нибудь пути совмещения эти двух, чтобы работали оба?

Comment: В каком смысле добавлю? `setText` заменяет всё содержимое `TextView`. Добавляет `append`

Comment: Ну, если  сделаю, например так: `pageContent.setText(addClickablePart(Html.fromHtml(pageConentStr)), TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);` То система обрабатывает текст тегами которые я добавил, но `spannable` перестает работать, сноски становятся цветом текста и не реагируют на клик.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сначала примените `Html.fromHtml` и делайте кликабельными ссылки уже с результатом этого метода:

```
 private SpannableStringBuilder addClickablePart(String str) {
    CharSequence sequence = Html.fromHtml(str);

    SpannableStringBuilder ssb = new SpannableStringBuilder(sequence);

    int idx1 = str.indexOf("[");
    int idx2 = 0;

    while (idx1 != -1) {
        idx2 = str.indexOf("]", idx1) + 1;

        String clickString = str.substring(idx1, idx2);

        ssb.setSpan(new ClickableSpan() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View widget) {

            }
        }, idx1, idx2, 0);
        idx1 = str.indexOf("[", idx2);
    }
    return ssb;
}
```

Comment: Заработало, однако, теперь кликабельное пространство не в квадратных скобках, а почему-то после квадратных скобок, дальше на 3-6-9-12 и так далее символом соответственно.

Comment: добавил в вопрос картинку с резульатом

Comment: @McDaggen, ну... Видимо что-то не так с алгоритмом установки кликабельных частей.

Comment: то есть вы знаете решения в моем случае?

Comment: @McDaggen, я знаю лишь, что задача решаема и знаю как её решить. В вашем вопросе спрашивается о соединении спанов с HTML. Мой ответ решает эту проблему. Задайте отдельный вопрос о том, что не так в вашем алгоритме. Вот так с ходу я не могу вам ответ дать - надо IDE запускать и прочая - это долго

Comment: Весьма хороший ответ, на самом деле, вы ответили мне, то что меня интересовало, всё остальное это уже другой вопрос.